# Как заполнять бинарное дерево?

Tags: бинарное-дерево, c++

Вот мне нужно составить бинарное дерево. К примеру у меня уже построено оно. Надо добавить 1 элемент. скажите пожалуйста, чем определяется то, куда он будет добавлен?

Comment: могу сказать только одно - новый элемент скорее всего будет подцеплен к одному из листов. Но как именно - это определяется структурой и свойствами дерева. У некоторых этот процесс далеко не тривиальный - в результате новый элемент может оказаться где то в середине дерева.

Comment: вы определяете то, куда элемент будет добавлен, у вас вопрос как определить то место и добавить?

Comment: @embarcadero, нет, я думал есть общая система-куда добавить.
Алгоритм то не проблема, я не знал просто как деревья устроены

Comment: да, есть общая система - на его законное место. А вот как оно определяется - это зависит от дерева.

Comment: @andrw: у вас бинарное дерево без всяких условий? тогда можно пройтись от корня вниз до упора и добавить, где остановились. если у вас, скажем, AVL-дерево или красно-чёрное, в них есть отдельно описанные алгоритмы вставки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Бинарные (и не только) деревья имеют свой корень (он запоминается). Потом оно (дерево) как-то обходится (может есть какое-то условие, нужна спец процедура) и добавляется элемент (так же нужна спец процедура).

Comment: А если допустима такая операция, как балансировка, то корень может потихоньку переползать на ветки. (Т.е. отношения родитель-потомок не являются существенными с точки зрения природы данных).